# I am struggling with associations with my models on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, scaffolding

I created a new rails application called imdb. I have created two models (via scaffolding) called `User` and `Movie`. I ran this in terminal.

```
rails g scaffold Movie title:string review:text location:string

rails g scaffold User name:string password_digest:string
```

I am finding it hard to imagine the associations that can be implemented into my application and need some help figuring this through.

We have these associations:

```
belongs_to,
has_one,
has_many,
has_many :through,
has_one :through,
has_and_belongs_to_many
```

I have so far thought that a 'user' can have many 'movies' and a 'movie' can have many 'users',  but unfortunately my mind has gone blank! Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: *"A [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association creates a direct many-to-many connection with another model"* sounds good :)

Comment: You should read this great explanation: http://habtmexample.herokuapp.com/instructions

Answer (score 0):

This probably seems confusing to you because there may not be any direct relationship between movies and user. If you had a third model Review this may make more sense.

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, inverse_of: movie
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, inverse_of: user
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie  
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create something like

```
Class User
has_many :movies

Class Movie
Belong_to :users
has_many :reviews :as => :reviewable


class Review
Belongs_to :movie
or
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :reviewable :polymorphic => true (this way this class can be reused later for more than movies and always written by user) 
has_many :comments :as => :commentable etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to a case where A user may have many roles, and a role may have many users when you work with permissions (admin, user, guest, banned, etc...).

If I wanted to create a model that could be used in association with other models independently I would use a Polymorphic association as Richardlonesteen. ex: I want to have reviews written by users for books and movies, but a review belongs either to a book or movie and not both.

Your solution is to use the `has_many :through` association. You will have 3 models: User, Movie, and another model that will tie the relationship between the Users and the Movies. For example purpose we will call this third model Screening, but it can be anything else. When you create you Screening model, you will also need a migration with two columns `user_id:integer movie_id:integer`, and make sure you index them both.

Your user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies, :through => :screenings
  has_many :screenings
  attr_accessible :username
end
```

Your movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through => :screenings
  has_many :screenings
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Your screening.rb

```
class Screening < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes are :user_id and :movie_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

Resulting with a relationship table that would look something like this

```
user_id | movie_id
------------------
    1   |    1
------------------
    1   |    2
------------------
    2   |    1
------------------
    3   |    2
```

Once you have this setup, you can fetch all movies of a user by doing `@user.movies` and vice-versa `@movie.users`. Rails will know how to find the associations.